# Print() for breaking line in python

Tags: python

I had to write a program to print the below pattern.

1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2
1

Now , the code which is given is as :

```py
num = int(input())

for i in range (1,num+1):
     for j in range (1 , i +1):
          print(j, end = " ")
     print()
```

But I don't understand that how a new line will be started after each loop without using \n  . My teacher told that the **print()** in the last is used to break line . But I don't understand that what is going on .

Comment: When you use `print(variable)`, the default value for `end` is a newline (`"\n"`) which is wht you call a breaking line. If you want to print a newline just use an empty print (`print()`), that should do the trick.

Comment: Ooh,  okay thanks .

Comment: Look at my answer plz. I raised a small remark

Comment: What is `Print`?

Comment: The `Print` should be changed into `print` as Python is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: Here, `end` arg. of `print` is given as `" "`, therefore will not print a newline after the `print` statement is executed. Therefore, to get to the next line, you have to give `print()`.

Comment: Sorry , it should be print and not Print

Answer (score 3):

See [this ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

> If no objects are given, print() will just write `end`.

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
// From above print function signature we know end is just '\n'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is right. By default, print() wraps. That said, you have to modify your code because this not return the output that you need.
There are many more optimized ways to do this but we'll base it on what you've done.

Try this

```
num = int(input())
for i in range(num, 0, -1):
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

`print()` is a function in python 3.x. It works kinda like `System.out.println();` in Java, in that it prints to a new line by default:

```
>>> print('line 1')
>>> print()
>>> print('line2')
line 1

line 2
```

You can control this via the `end` keyword (`'\n'` by default). Example:

```
>>> print('something', end = ' ')
>>> print('some other thing')
something some other thing
```

So when someone says `print()` is used to break line, it's the same as adding a newline char.

Answer (score 0):

By default, print function has **end='\n'** as argument. That's why it provides a new line after its' execution.
you can change that with anything, like end=' '(this will put an extra space ), end = '.' (this will add a full stop at the end)

the print function bears this Infos

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```